# Twitter Bootstrap Overlay Carousel on Hero Unit

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and I want to overlay the carousel element over the hero-unit element. How can I achieve this?

The reason being is that if I insert an image inside the hero unit element it re-sizes it nicely for me, whereas if I set it to the background image it is just cropped when re-sizing.

Please advise?

Comment: Can you post the code that you've tried?

Comment: Do you mean something like this http://www.bootply.com/68866, or you want the entire hero to be a carousel image?